# How can I agglomerate similar rows in a pivot sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data sheet where are stored numerous matches that I played. Each match has a number of relevant columns such as *Opponent* and *Result*.

I have made a pivot sheet that counts for each opponent the number of wins across the data sheet.

The problem is that the table will record every misspell of the value for opponent separately.

Is there a way to agglomerate rows (and sum the counts) depending on how similar they are?

Comment: Nothing built in for spelling error recognition. You'll have to find a way to normalize those names somehow, probably using Apps Script and [something like this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23305385)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Fuzzy match addin?
It will help you correct these misspelled names in one go
[image] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-fuzzy-matches/cadkkijbhldndjaflcbapfllpolajpcp?hl=en

Add it from the chrome webstore and let it run on your sheet.
P.S Fuzzy match is also available for Excel

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay. I don't want to fix the mispellings though, I want them to be merged in my pivot sheet.